# How to Power Motor From Alarm

Tags: voltage, ac

I have an alarm clock that beeps at a known    time. I wish to power a motor every time it rings, but the problem is that there isn't enough power to turn the motor. I attempted to connect a wire in parallel to the wire that connects the circuit to the beeper though that still doesn't work. When power is applied this way , there is still somehow a voltage drop and the beeper cannot beep as loud and the motor is unable to turn (I tried in series as a desperate attempt). What I am trying to achieve is to power an AC motor from a weak "signal pulse". Any suggestions how to do this? Do I need some form of relay?

Answer (score 1):

A technically simple answer is use a relay. The beeper energizes an electromagnet with the low voltage beeper signal, and the electromagnet pulls in a switch contact which completes a separate circuit connected to the motor.

Search on 5VDC relay for lots of ideas.

If the motor you are considering uses 120VAC you might want to avoid it for safety reasons.

Comment: If I am unable to get a relay, would there possibly another way with just batteries, wire, resistors? Thank you for your response, and I will try to get a relay if possible.

Comment: But the signal might be too weak to even power a relay by itself. In that case you have to switch the relay using a transistor. There are modules readily available that combine these two components, so you just need a high/low input signal with neglectable current. Search for something like `arduino relay` and you will find lots of such modules...

Comment: @IanLimarta Here's something you should also know. **Buy a diode-protected relay**. When you disconnect a relay's coil from the power source, a thing called _EM Flyback_ occurs. I'm not going to go into the deep details here, but all you need to know is that ***freaky stuff happens with electromagnetic fields that causes it to surge with extreme power in the reverse polarity***. Diode protected relays are designed to protect against this kind of thing. Learn more about EM flyback [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode#Working_principle)

Comment: I can't think of any way without some type of switching device like a relay or transistor.  And as Chindocaine commented there is no guarantee that the beeper signal is strong enough to operate the electromagnet (called the 'coil') of the relay, but it would be a simple answer if it worked.  Anytime you want to operate a power hungry device, like a motor, with a tiny signal you need a way to control the larger signal with the weaker one. That is the magic of transistors. Before transistors relays were often used. I suggested a relay because they are much easier to understand than transistors.

Comment: Just as a safety precaution. Would a toy car motor that requires 4 1.5 V batteries necessarily be 6 V? If so, would this be a safety problem?

Comment: The danger of a shock hazard is pretty much zero with 4 1.5v batteries. With a small motor like that you may be able to connect it directly to the beeper output.  In that case the motor is a DC motor. The next question would be to ask is the beeper signal DC or AC?  Since we don't know yet, that could stop it from working. If it does not work at first, a diode connected is series with the motor would be a crude rectifier to turn the AC into very rough DC, just to see if the motor will respond.